# GTK non-standard input

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to have a piano key interpreted as a keyboard input.  I am receiving the piano key number over UART on the Raspberry Pi.  I have a GUI made in C using GTK and when I detect certain piano keys I need them to be sent as keyboard enter or arrow keys to navigate the GUI.  Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather you don't want the piano key to be interpreted as a keyboard input; rather, you want the piano key to be handled the same way as the keyboard input is.  On receiving the specified piano key event, have it call the same function that the corresponding keyboard key does.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux the easiest way to do what you need is to use the XTest extension to X11, particularly the function `XTestFakeKeyEvent`.

But don't forget to call `XTestQueryExtension` to initialize the extension! It is a common pitfall: if you do not call to this function the other `XTest*` functions will not work at all!

You can also make you piano a real keyboard writing a user-space driver: you can create input devices and send input events to the kernel by using the `uinput` kernel driver: basically it creates a `/dev/uinput` device that you can manipulate with `ioctl`s to do whatever you need.